# Gitlab trigger daily jenkins jobs using webhooks

Tags: jenkins, gitlab

I'm looking for a way on how to trigger periodical Jenkins jobs using gitlab (14.2.3-ee) webhooks.

As of now the Jenkins Gitlab integration is working using Push or TagPush events. But how can I schedule periodical build events?

I have seen the option for CI Schedules in gitlab, but this will only execute the gitlab pipeline.
How can I trigger the Jenkins pipeline for such events?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a simple scheduled gitlab pipeline to call webhook.

A simple job like this should be sufficient :

```yaml
# Exec pipeline only on scheduled pipeline
workflows:
  rules:
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "schedule"

trigger-jenkins:
  stage: build
  image: curlimages/curl:7.81.0
  script:
    - curl ${JENKINS_WEBHOOK_URL}
```

You have to put this code in a `.gitlab-ci.yml` file and scheduled pipelines in *CI/CD* -> *Schedules* menu in Gitlab project UI.

Comment: Ok, this sounds already very promising. Can I also detect the scheduled trigger in Jenkins e.g. by checking the value of gitlabActionType?

Comment: I think you can't, my solution is not linked with Jenkins Gitlab plugin. It's just a simple HTTP call to run your Jenkins job. You can use it with the native Remote Access API: https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/using/remote-access-api/#RemoteaccessAPI-Submittingjobs

Comment: Thanks a lot! I understood the way how the Jenkins job is triggered. All in all I'm not super happy with the gitlab / Jenkins Integration when it comes to time based triggers. It would be very handy if they could provide a similar approach as for the other actions (push, comment, etc...).